# Should alternative solutions be posted as separate answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Often a question has more than one alternative solution, especially when it is a recommendation of a product or library. Many answers suggest a list of solutions or recommendations. The problem is that the lists in the different answers may the refer the same product, while many of the lists are not full, they just overlap. So to get the full list of solutions one needs to scan and combine the lists in all the answers. There is additional problem that the solution lists become outdated.

This is an example: [XSLT Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623827/xslt-unit-testing)

It is OK, but I believe it would be better if each answer contained exactly one solution. In this way, it would be easy to read the topic and the votes would reflect the popularity of solutions. With this approach adding newer solutions to the list would look cleaner.

What I mean is that if one going to list alternatives in their answer is not it better to post several answers: one for each alternative?

Comment: Let's back up one half step first and get this out of the way: you're not talking about questions that are _asking for_ lists of product recommendations, are you? Those questions -- due to **precisely** the problems you're talking about their answers having -- are not welcome on Stack Overflow and should be _closed_, not answered.

Comment: I know that questions asking for product recommendations should be closed. I am talking about a questions about a specific problem, which come to have several possible solutions such as using different libraries or tools.

Comment: Excellent; just wanted to make sure that was the case!

Comment: I added an example of a question

Comment: Actually, your example question is rather bad. It boils down to "I have an XSLT, how can I test it automatically", which is a resource request in disguise as the answers could either be "use a test framework" or "write your own test framework" (which is of course too broad). All answers are just references to external resources which is bad as well. Re your question: IMO if there are multiple programming solutions which can't be shown and explained in a reasonably short answer, the answer should be split up. It doesn't make sense to do so for link-only answers like in the example question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two solutions - one or two answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269545/two-solutions-one-or-two-answers), or perhaps the one that one was marked as a duplicate of: [Are multiple answers by the same user acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251070/are-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-acceptable)