# How to deal with multiple answers in the same answer?

Tags: discussion

Can't find any topics on this (maybe due to ambiguous search terms), but say I came across an answer that contained multiple answers to a question, to try various solutions for example. Is this acceptable or should it be flagged?

If it's acceptable, and one of the answers in the answer solved the question, should the answer then be edited for future readability?

If the latter, should it be flagged *Not an answer* or *Low quality*?

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: Related: [Two solutions - one or two answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269545/two-solutions-one-or-two-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's worth flagging, but I do think that different solutions to the same problem should be separated. One of the key features of Stack Overflow is that the best answers bubble up to the top with voting, so we don't want to make people read through one or two useless answers that are mixed in with the correct one. If I saw multiple answers in one, I'd leave a comment asking the author to split it up into multiple posts. Comments clarifying which answer was helpful would be welcome as well.

(I probably wouldn't accept such an answer to one of my own questions, but if I did I would edit the answer so that the one that helped the most was at the top.)

Comment: Not so much different solutions that would both work, different solutions that say only one of them will work but it would depend on the original posters response as to which will work.

Comment: @Matt In that case, I would ask for clarifying comments first, but both answers might be useful to different people in the future.

Comment: In your opinion, Bill... should I go back and break [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element/8716680#8716680) into multiple posts?

Comment: @canon That's a good example, the kind of which I hadn't thought of. I wouldn't split that up because of the nature of the question. It's asking for a canonical troubleshooting guide, so I think your answer is a good resource (relevant user name!). If it had been asking the same question about a specific piece of code, then you'd probably want to split that up so the OP could accept the answer that worked best for them.

Comment: What should be the best comment text when we desire to downvote an answer for that reason? "Please break your multiple answers as different replies to this question. This will help vote & comment on your individual answers."?

Comment: @SandRock That text sounds good. I'd have to look at specific cases, but most of these kinds of answers that I see don't really warrant a downvote.

Comment: There are a few where a second answer is hidden in a big content with no obvious-to-the-eye separation. The best would be to split. Another way is to use titles to clearly show the different options.

Answer (score 1):

My personal view on this situation is that each answer should aim to be a distinct solution to the problem. Of course this can vary case by case, some solutions are very tightly related, so you might provide a few different ways of using arguments for example. But if they are distinct solutions they should be posted as distinct answers.

The main benefit to this is that these solutions can then be voted and discussed independently. There might be a good and bad way of solving a problem, but both do technically work. So the good solution can be voted up with out being marred by the bad solution. At the same time, this means the bad solution will get down-voted, and whilst it might not be a good solution, it does at least solve the problem. Others might learn something from knowing that it is *a solution*; there might be some scenario where it becomes the only solution, even if it is not that nice.

As for editing these to make them distinct, I really don't know. I sort of feel that it is better, and people should not feel too protective over their answers.

Regarding flagging or down-voting, I think that is a bit excessive. The answer is wrong, or bad, it just covers more than it should, so perhaps just a comment.