# Should I advocate for a single user posting multiple answers instead of putting two distinct solutions in one post?

Tags: discussion, answers, multiple-answers

I recently asked a question in which one user indicated they had another solution and that they'd update their post.  I suggested they add a second answer.  Their response was that they'd do what is customary and edit their existing post.

Should I advocate for posting multiple answers?  I think it's cleaner to separate distinct answers as votes for one answer aren't convoluted with the "goodness" of the other and vice-versa.

My initial interpretation was that I may have offended the individual and I'm looking for explanations as to why that may or may not have been the case.

Comment: I want to find a source for this, and I think that'll be a dupe target for this question, but pretty sure people generally suggest _two_ answers when the two solutions are _distinct, separate_ solutions. This way, each solution can be voted on separately, depending on how good they are.

Comment: Relevant answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314024/2607247

Comment: Thanks @Kendra.  I found other questions that addressed the right an wrong of it.  I wanted to understand why this person seemed offended.  And if I should advocate for something that is secretly despised among the SO community.

Comment: Honestly, without seeing the specific scenario, it's hard to say why they reacted that way, or if they actually seemed offended or you just interpreted it that way. As far as I'm aware, though, separate answers is the actual custom, not editing a separate solution into the same answer.

Comment: @Kendra That's good to hear.  And I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I hadn't felt there was a problem with [my posting an alternate approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38573953/4151918) within the same answer, since one approach wasn't intended to compete (or disagree) with the other. Yet I can appreciate the merit mentioned in [Bill the Lizard's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314024/4151918) of seeing which approach was more liked in the long term.